# In SPF how do you authorize any server on my domains to send

Tags: postfix, spf

I have multiple domains with multiple mailservers on each. they all send with the same return path address. so x@bounce.bouncesent.com for instance.

I want to authorize any host on my domains ( abx.com, sksk.com, rwfjsdj.com and sssdr.com ) to send for x@bounce.bouncesent.com.

The domains listed above are mine and do not have spf records at this time.

I tried

v=spf1 a a:abx.com a:sksk.com a:rwfjsdj.com sssdr.com ~all

but that did not seem to work,because I may have multiple mailservers for abx.com etc.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can allow each domain's MX in that particular domain's SPF record. Then for the 'bounce.bouncesent.com' domain, `include` the other domains

```
TXT  "v=spf1 mx include:aaa.com include:bbb.com -all"
```

Answer (score 1):

Wildcard SPF should in theory work (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4408#section-3.1.5) but the reality is that it isn't totally reliable.
It isn't too hard to setup the individual entries per domain in form of

`v=spf1 a mx a:mx1.example1.com a:mx1.example2.com a:mx1.example3.com ~all`

but some dns setups have a limit of the number of servers you have. It may be better to do it by IP address if the domains are hosted on the same box. Will give less maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the wildcard record for IN TXT, eg:

```
* IN TXT "v=spf1 -all"
```

Comment: you mean have this entry in each of my domains and then include it in the bounce.bouncesent.com spf record?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you meant you wants subdomains of those domains all authenticated. SPF works based on IP addresses; not domains - so you can authorize the list of IPs that will be sending mail for bounce.bouncesent.com or the other domains.

Comment: SPF *does* allow domain names. See http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax for examples